# How do I keep my outdoor trash cans from blowing away in the wind?

Tags: trash-can

I have two trash cans that sit on the side of my house. What can I do to keep them from blowing away due to the wind, when they are empty? I've tried bungee cording them together but they then just blow away as a couple. I have concrete block so I thought I could maybe attach hooks and use bungee cords to secure them to the house.

Comment: Is duct tape an acceptable solution? :)

Comment: @Doresoom: Does not pass the Wife test

Comment: Construction adhesive! :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your idea of a bungee cording the trash cans to the side of the house might be the easiest option. (Other than duct tape.) You could try a set of [D-rings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HZXPOE) and [concrete screws](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MRHQBW) for that. Just make sure they'll be rust-resistant.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I ended up using eyebolts and epoxied them into the wall.

Answer (score 12):

I've seen some houses near me have a sort of cage for them -- looks like a little fenced-off area on the side of the house, with the trash cans in there, and can swing open in front to get the trash cans out.

If it's *really* windy, you might need to add a top to it, so the trash cans can't lift out in high winds.

Comment: By *really* windy do you mean cows flying past in a tornado?

Comment: @doresoom : Um ... anyone with a good understanding of the bernoulli effect about to calculate the wind speed necessary to create a pressure differential sufficient to overcome gravity?

Of course, if you used slats such that wind could pass underneath the trash cans, too as they begin lifting, it might reduce the likelihood of them escaping.

Comment: I assume the cage is as much to prevent animals from intruding as to prevent the cans from doing a "Dorothy".

Comment: @Doresoom : a 2kg trash can?  That might be a bit heavy for an empty plastic one these days, but as it's over 900mph winds, I don't think it'd be an issue at even 1/4 that weight, as you'd be well into hurricane-strength winds.

Comment: @Joe: Sorry, I was a bit of a jerk there. I took several classes with my ME major that involved using the Bernoulli effect extensively, and my pride got hurt there.

Comment: @Doresoom : no problem -- I was a CivE major, so never had to deal with Bernoilli, other than Bernoilli equations in DiffEq.

Answer (score 5):

We used to get excellent results on this same problem by using cinder blocks. I'd just leave them around the garbage cans like a border, and wedge the cans inside them. It works surprisingly well, and it's simple, requiring no construction.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the bungie cords you could put up a post (wood, metal) in between them attached to a heavy block on the ground, put a hook/D-Ring near the top, and then wrap the bungie cord around each can attaching it to the post.