# Stopping wheelie bins blowing over in the wind

Tags: trash-can

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I keep my outdoor trash cans from blowing away in the wind?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/how-do-i-keep-my-outdoor-trash-cans-from-blowing-away-in-the-wind)

I am looking for a simple and cheap way to stop our wheelie bins blowing over, we keep then next to a wall, so some type of fixing may be an option.

However any solution must be easy to attach and detect without requiring a high level of 
fine motor skills as my wife has Cerebral Palsy and I don’t wish to give her a reason to always make me put the bins out!

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to drill the wall and attach metal fixings you could use nylon webbing with some heavy duty velcro to make simple retaining straps. They'd be anchored to the wall fixings so  you'd just need to do/undo the velcro to fasten/release. Here in the UK our wheelie bins have a 'loop' as part of their hinge structure and this has proved perfect for looping the webbing through.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a cinder block or two in the bottom and lock it in place with Great Stuff foam.  If you are really ambitious, you could cut a plywood false bottom and seal around the edges so that the garbage goo doesn't collect in the bottom too much.

Comment: Our bins only get emptied every 2 weeks and we often get close to filling them up.  Also making the bins heavy will make it harder for my wife to move them.

Comment: The garbage men will HATE you!

Comment: The garbage men don't care....I haven't seen a wheelie bin emptied by hand in 10 years. They use a hydraulic arm.

Comment: I think the people who made this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh2dnaXM8Kw) had cinder blocks in the bottom of their can.

Comment: The garbage men for our neighborhood just leave the trashcan full if it's too heavy.